# Manage questions from multiple Stack Exchange sites on the same page

Tags: support, questions, stack-exchange, user-interface

Recently, I've gotten really involved in Stack Exchange. I'm asking questions on multiple Stack Exchange sites. For each Stack Exchange site I know that you can go to the user page and see questions I've asked, but is there a way to see all the questions I have asked across multiple Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/users/2915856/ideorex?tab=activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to [your main Stack Exchange profile page](https://stackexchange.com/users/2915856/ideorex?tab=activity), then click **activity**, then **posts** you can see all of your questions and answers across all sites. It would be kind of nice if questions and answers could be separated.

(Your SE profile is linked under **Accounts** on each individual site profile.  Click the "view more" link.)

Comment: The **top** tab separates by question and answer, but only includes posts with a score of at least 5.